# What is DRTC in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. Season 1 episode 3?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

Ian Quinn refers to an organization called DRTC whose regulations inhibit Quinn Worldwide's ability "to pursue progress and profit." He even throws a logo on screen.

[image: DRTC]

Anyone know what it is?

Comment: from the internet, it appears to not have been answered yet, unless it is in a more recent episode.

Comment: Agree with Himarm after google searching. Looks like something yet to be explained.

Comment: Who is the girl in the middle? She has got fancy hair.

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a completely fictional organization. I can find no evidence of a real DRTC anything like the one from the show.

It may have been a dropped plot-thread, as two seasons on, there still hasn't been an explanation.

There is a [DRTC](http://drtc.isibang.ac.in/DRTC/) in India, but it is highly unlikely that that's the one he was talking about as, among other reasons, the Indian DRTC doesn't have the same white and blue triangle logo as *S.H.I.E.L.D.*'s.

Comment: AoS was definitely still trying to find its footing until The Winter Soldier was released. Rising Tide looked like it was going to be a major player but was forgotten almost as quickly as it was introduced. So it makes sense that this was dropped, too.